# SQL Server find and replace in TEXT field

Tags: sql-server-2005, text

I have a database in SQL Server 2005 that was brought up from SQL Server 2000 and is still using TEXT type fields instead of varchar(max).

I need to find and replace a string of characters in the text field but all of the examples of how to do this that I have found don't seem like they would work for me. It seems the UPDATETEXT command requires that the two parameters "insert_offset" and "delete_length" be set explicitly but the string i am searching for could show up in the text at any point or even at several points in the same cell. My understanding of these two parameters is that the string im searching for will always be in the same place, so that insert_offset is the number of spaces into the text that the UPDATETEXT command will start replacing text.

Example: Need to find: `&lt;u&gt;` and Replace it with: `<u>`

Text field example:

```
*Everyone in the room was <b>&lt;u&gt;tired&lt;/u&gt;.</b><br>Then they woke <b>&lt;u&gt;up&lt;/u&gt;.
```

Can anyone help me out with this? THANKS!

Answer (score 83):

I finally figured it out. It was buried in the comments to the article jfrobishow published. Thank you SO much.

Here is the whole response that led me to the solution:

> quote:Originally posted by fredclown
>
> If you use SQL 2005 you can use replace with a text type. All you have
>   to do is the below ...
>
> field = replace(cast(field as varchar(max)),'string' ,'replacement')
>
> Easy as pie.
>
> Two thumbs up to Fredclown!!! command
>   work like a charm for me as well. This
>   is what I wrote my Update statement to
>   Find and Replace in a Text field in
>   SQL server 2005 database

```
UPDATE TableName SET DBTextField = REPLACE(CAST(DBTextField AS varchar(MAX))
                                               ,'SearchText', 'ReplaceText')
FROM TableName
WHERE CHARINDEX('SearchText',CAST(DBTextField as varchar(MAX)))>0
```

**Note:that** this may **truncate** the size of you dbfield , but if is a long text column make it **nvarchar(max)** and you should not get none truncation!

Comment: warning: this will crop the content of the textfield to 8000 chars

Comment: @incubushead thank you. I know it's an old post but this specific syntax offered by you directly helped me live on a client site with something that was going to be longwinded and hard work other wise, so thank you. Anyone stuck with an ntext field - I was, Don't cast to ntext (doesn't work AND is deprecated), simply use varchar(max) as given here; it works just. The cast doesn't alter the column type, just how the update behaves-also use don't miss out MAX if text is a bit longer than a few characters else your truncated to 50 chars.

Comment: What if you want to REMOVE strings and not replace them at all with anything?

Comment: The CHARINDEX function will not work correctly on text fields bigger than 8000 characters

Comment: @incubushead thank you.   Late in mid-2017 your answer has helped another..