# SQL wont let me replace a quote in SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to remove double quotes `"` from a column in my SQL export and I get an error, after researching the proper way... this is one of  the ways I have tried....

```
SELECT 
   '293453' as custnum, 
   REPLACE(Orders.Order_Comments, '"', '') as FULFILL1, 
   OrderDetails.OrderID as OrderID2, etc.
```

The resulting error is:

> Your SQL is invalid: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: what's the datatype of the `order_comments` field?  [t-sql replace() function...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) i wonder what happens if that field is ever `null`...?

Comment: what is this '293453' ??

Comment: @prashantthakre, that's a string literal :).

Comment: then first you should remove `'293453' as custnum,`  from your select statement

Comment: @prashantthakre No, what he's doing with the string literal is perfectly okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [SQL Server find and replace in TEXT field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641068/sql-server-find-and-replace-in-text-field/2641280#2641280)

The `text` data type is not valid for use with `replace`, so you need to cast it as VARCHAR(MAX)

```
REPLACE(CAST(Orders.Order_Comments AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '"', '')
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Orders.Order_Comments` columns is of type [`text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). You can't use the REPLACE() function with that data type. It only works with char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar.

To fix this, the best thing to do is ALTER the table to use a `varchar(max)` column. The `text` type is depcrecated, anyway. But, if that's not an option, you'll have to cast it in the query:

```
REPLACE(CAST(Orders.Order_Comments as varchar(max)), '"', '')
```

Note that this is potentially *very* slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  REPLACE(isnull(Orders.Order_Comments,''), '"', '') as order_comments
from    orders
```