# why text or ntext is not recomended for use in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

please discuss the reason why why text or ntext is not recomended for use in sql server. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are deprecated, won't work in future versions and working with them is a pain compared to the replacement datatypes (`varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)`) as most string functions don't work with them.

Comment: i just want to know what type of problem people faced using text and ntext. please list those.

Comment: [Here's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289688/t-sql-replace-on-text-field/304643#304643) This answer gives code required to do a `REPLACE` operation on a column with `text` datatype. With `varchar(max)` you jut use the `REPLACE` function!